# ReSharper Integrate with VS build

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, resharper, integration

I have VS2008 professional and i installed ReSharper. The R# does work well and analyzes the code but what i need is to integrate the R# analysis with VS Build so that when i make a build (in Debug/Release), i should be able to see those suggestions/warnings by R# in the VS Error List Window. Also getting a report of the same is appreciated.
Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity, also from JetBrains, is a build system that has the ability to provide the ReSharper errors and warnings as part of your build.

I'm aware that this isn't MS Build, though.